# Rendering a map with an API in react native

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

I am currently trying to build a currency convertor with react native but I cannot seem to render this API data back as a map and then into a rate. If anyone can guide me I would  really appreciate. I would like to use the API response as a number and mathematically calculate input and provide out which is the users input converted.

The error Im getting is that undefined is not a function(near '...this.state.rates.map...')

The commented out part is to be ignored.

The following is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Text, View, Alert} from 'react-native';

const rate = 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=GBP_PKR&compact=ultra&apiKey=59825436b2556cde7205';

class Rates extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            rates: 1,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=GBP_PKR&compact=ultra&apiKey=59825436b2556cde7205')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({rates: data.rate}));
        console.log(rates.data);
    }
    render() {

        const rateNumber = this.state.rates.map(function(listItem, index){
            <View key={index}>
            <Text> {listItem.rate}</Text>
            </View>
        });

        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Rate for today </Text>
                <Text>{rateNumber}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Rates;
```

**App**

```
import React from 'react';
import {ListView, StyleSheet,RefreshControl, Text,TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

import Rates from './data/Rates';


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gbp: '',
      pkr: '',
      rate: [],
    }
  }

  /*componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=GBP_PKR&compact=ultra&apiKey=59825436b2556cde7205')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data=> this.setState({ rate: [data] }));
  }
  */


  convert() {
    const gbp = this.state.gbp;
    const pkr = this.state.pkr;

    const total = gbp*pkr;

    console.log(total);
  }
  render() {
    const rate = this.state;
    const amount = JSON.stringify(rate.rate);


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View>
          <Text>{amount}</Text>
          <View><Rates/></View>
        </View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="GBP"
          value={this.state.gbp}
          onChangeText={(gbp) => this.setState({ gbp })}
          keyboardType='numeric'
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="PKR"
          value={this.state.pkr}
          onChangeText={(pkr) => this.setState({ pkr })}
          keyboardType='numeric'
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.refreshDataFromServer()}>
          <Text value={this.state.rate}> Convert</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


export default App;
```

Comment: In the constructor, I would use `this.state = { rates: [] }` as `map()` is not a function for `Number` type

Comment: Noted, anything else?

Comment: Since fetch request takes time, at least the first render() of the component has an undefined `this.state.rates`. So you need to control it and use `map()` only if `this.state.rates` is not undefined. Something like `const rateNumber = this.state.rates && this.state.rates.map(...)`

Comment: Also note that you can't render that array of `View` in a `Text`, so change it to a more appropriate component.